# Is there a way to know when one of my comments gets "upvoted"?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, comment-voting

If I leave a comment and someone liked it, is there a way to see it?

If not... why not? It's something that would be nice to know.

Comment: +10 rep for asking.

Comment: started a bounty because all the cool kids are doing it

Comment: Honestly I don't see the point.  In my opinion, if you need this kind of thing, you're on the site too much.

Comment: @Down with the Samp: Is that even possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion in the past about wanting to be able to view comment history and recent activity like votes and such, but nothing has come about it yet (seems to be very popular, though).

I imagine that at some point in time the commenting system will grow in overall robustness. I just can't really say when that will happen. Maybe in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Maybe in 6 to 8 years -.-

Comment: @ThomasBonini Doesn’t look like it...

Answer (score 14):

Not without going back and actually looking. I suppose the team feels upvotes are pretty trivial when it comes to comments. Their triviality is the reason why you can't edit comments, or downvote them. They're a dime a dozen, and they don't earn you any reputation either.

Comment: In some cases I leave a comment adding something to the answer someone's left, and it can be nice to know if people agree with me without having to start the question and come back later.

Comment: Yeah; I agree. It would be nice, but the team doesn't appear to be interested in updating the commenting-system. In all honesty, while I like the ideas, I can understand that they probably have heavier tasks to deal with.

Comment: don't follow-on comments show up in your 'responses' ?

Comment: @warren: this comment will notify you, in your recent activity area (the envelope)... :-)

Comment: @studiohack - yes, if you "@" someone it shows up .. but not otherwise

Answer (score 14):

It's not real time, but you could query the [data dump](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/) to see the comments you've left along with their score at the time of the snapshot of the database.

Use [something like this](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=select%20score,%20concat%28%27%3ca%20href=%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/%27,%20postid,%20%27%22%3e%27,text,%20%20%27%3c/a%3e%27%29%20as%20comment%20from%20comments%20where%20userid=%2790691%27%20order%20by%20score%20desc):

```
SELECT score, 
  concat('<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/', PostId, '">',text, 
  '</a>') as comment
FROM comments 
WHERE userid='90691' 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

You can also use it to work out how close you are/were to getting a [Pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit).

Comment: +1 Nice — while I agree with what Jonathan said about the understandability of SO team keeping the commenting system relatively simple, etc, it's still interesting to see if I'm getting close to that badge (no) =)

Comment: That makes sense so +1. It's a bit violent thought :)

Comment: +1 - can't believe I didn't think to try this...

Comment: The links are broken...

Answer (score 8):

I agree - I find it odd that you can't easily find this information when the ultra-rare [Pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) exists to specifically encourage excellent comments. It doesn't seem unreasonable to want to know whether even one of your comments, lost somewhere on the site, has achieved a rating of 10... (although I don't think I've ever got above a 2 for a comment, so no danger there for me personally - but then, there's no way for me to actually *know* that ;).

Comment: There are badges for editing as well, but no way of viewing how many edits are made. I suspect it's a matter of wanting to encourage the practice (editing, commenting) *in general*, but not as a game.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. Although watching the votes is more like an ego issue, knowing there has been activity on a thread that you posted in can be relevant. I wrote a [mini-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9032/) to watch these things. It's not pretty, but it works (for me, anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [random's hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19938/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-one-of-my-comments-gets-upvoted/22107#22107) to use the data dumps, here's some stored queries to see how close you are to a Pundit badge:

- [Count of how many comments you have at each score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104015/comment-scores-by-user?UserId=1)
- [Link to all your comment posts, sorted by score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104018/user-comments?UserId=1)

Comment: dead links, please change.

Comment: Links replaced.

Answer (score 2):

**New version:**

Using API 2.2:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-comments#order=desc&sort=votes&filter=default

---

**Old version:**

Here's an API link (using version 1.1, I know):

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/90691/comments?sort=votes

It shows you all of your comments, most upvoted at the top. Add `&min=5` to specify a minimum number of upvotes.

For anyone else wanting to use this, replace `90691` with your user ID on Main.