# Any search terms for comments by a particular user?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Can we have a search term to discover comments by a particular user? I've tried a few permutations without success.

Something along the lines of:

```
user:me comment:1
```

Note, I'm aware that [I can search old comments in comments.xml](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=select%20%0D%0A%20%20%20concat%28%27%3Ca%20href=%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com/posts/%27,%20postid,%20%27/comments%23comment-%27,%20id,%20%27%22%3E%27,%20text,%20%27%3C/a%3E%3Cbr%3E%28on%20post%20%23%3Ca%20href=%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com/questions/%27,%20postid,%20%27%22%3E%27,%20postid,%20%27%3C/a%3E%29%27%29%20as%20comment%0D%0A%20%20%20from%20comments%0D%0A%20where%20userid=123582%0D%0A%20%20order%20by%20creationdate%20desc) from the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/).

Comment: You can find the newest ones on the user's "recent" page. But that's probably not enough for what you want.

Comment: @balpha, Yes it's the ones I vaguely remember from a few weeks back I'm thinking of.

Comment: related to my question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19938/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-one-of-my-comments-gets-upvoted

Answer (score 1):

**No.  There isn't, and there should not be.**

SO is about Questions and Answers, not comments.  There has been a constant squeeze on comment-related features and it should stay that way.

Anything with URLs is just light weight hack-ish.

Who are you trying to stalk, anyway?

Comment: just this geek: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2961

Comment: I'm onto Rich Seller.  Stop sending pony-shaped chocolates to my at the office!  My boss thinks it's weird.

Answer (score -2):

Yep, and you already know how to do it. :) Replace `me` with the user's numeric ID. I just did a search for your comments here on meta by doing:

```
user:130494 comment:1
```

Now, of course, this shows a list of questions where you have comments -- so if you need something more granular, yes, you need the data dump or the sandbox.

Comment: This doesn't work exactly, it appears to filter based on questions either asked or answered by the user, that have comments attached to the question. I believe Rich wants to find questions which he has commented on

Comment: I think @Nathan has it right, for instance I just commented on this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/are-we-too-rep-focused, which does not appear in the search http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a130494%20comment%3a1&tab=newest
I think it just appeared to work because I've commented on most of my posts on meta

Comment: @Rich: I think that part of it is the age of the question itself, and yes, you're going to probably be in a mode of hitting the data dump. The question you commented on (one of mine, no less!) is older than the most recent (and less active than the most active) 25 on which you commented. So in essence, performing this search only seems to give 25 results ... And thus, here we set. I'm checking to see if I can hack the URL to get more results, but I have my doubts.