# How can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?

Tags: support, comments, search, data-explorer

Here's my problem: I *know* I've posted something on Stack Overflow about a particular topic.  I know how to search all my **answers** with a given keyword, and that feature works well.  But, if I don't find anything, I assume that it must have been a **comment** that I posted on the subject, and I'd like to be able to find it, and the question it belongs to.

I have read:

[this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771/186251), [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31236/186251), and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22171/186251) on Meta.

Basically, all the responses to those are about 3 years old, so it seems reasonable (to me) to ask this again ...

I've also tried just searching on Google with the keyword(s), my SO username (which I guess unfortunately is (a) not that unusual, and (b) a substring of other words, like *unfortunately*!), and `site:stackoverflow.com`, without much success.

Is there a Stack Exchange API or *query* that I could run to search my comments, using a keyword or keywords?

I did see one [response by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23786/186251) in one of the questions linked to above indicating that the (2009) inability to do this was annoying him, too, so hopefully I'm not the only one who's tried to do this.

Comment: +1 @Nate I didn't see yours when I posted mine. But I also asked for some limited `retag/folder` features in [my question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161830/can-we-search-the-inbox-or-comments-tab)

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183142/ability-to-search-comments-would-be-useful/189435#189435) helps.

Comment: @yorkw, yes, it definitely does!  Although I'd love it to be built into the stack exchange web application itself, your query seems to do what I wanted.  If you'd like to post your answer again here, I will accept it as a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Related, but asking if there's an existing on-site page that provides this functionality: [Finding my own comments on questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066/997587)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I have created [a data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=wait&UserId=130127) to search a post by comment texts and userId:

```sql
SELECT Id AS [Comment Link], Score, Text 
  FROM Comments 
 WHERE UPPER(Text) LIKE UPPER('%##CommentText##%')
   AND UserId = '##UserId##'
 ORDER BY Score DESC
```

I have also created a query to search for multiple keywords:

- Using [`AND` operator](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/151791/search-posts-by-multiple-comment-text-and-operator-and-userid?CommentText=wait&CommentText2=ok&UserId=130127) (comments contain both keywords)
- Using [`OR` operator](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/151788/search-posts-by-multiple-comment-text-or-operator-and-userid?CommentText=wait&CommentText2=ok&UserId=130127) (comments contain either or both keywords)

You can edit the query to customize it for your use.

Comment: Just a heads-up that, for example, if you want to search stackoverflow.com for comments, using a stack overflow user Id, you would replace `meta.stackoverflow` in your data explorer query URL with just `stackoverflow`.

Comment: Yup @Nate. You have to switch the site you want to search in. I have provided the link for Meta.SO.

Comment: is there anyway that I can filter responses I got from a user?

Comment: For anyone using these queries to search Russian: you'll need to use N-strings in `LIKE`-patterns, as done here: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/775629/960188/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80&UserId=181100

Comment: Do you know how to sort by descending date?

Comment: @Noitidart : [Here you go...](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/847320/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=wait&UserId=130127)

Comment: For complete SQL newbies like me, you need to remove the #s from the search terms and your user id. :D

Comment: Can you please explain the `[Comment Link]` query part, what is that syntax (`[...]`) meaning? Is it possible to somehow add the thread question title to this query results?

Comment: Managed to do it via `SELECT Id AS [Comment Link], PostId AS [Post Link], ...` yet still don't understand where that `AS [Comment Link]` and `AS [Post Link]` are come from or where they are documented. Many thanks for this excellent query, BTW.

Comment: @IvanShatsky: Those are *Magic Columns* specially designed for SEDE. There are [few more](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns).

Comment: In a [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392953) it is recommended both [in the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392958) and in some comments to use `COLLATE` rather than `UPPER(Text) LIKE UPPER('%##CommentText##%')`. (It seems that this might be a problem mainly on bigger sites where the Comments table is large.)

Answer (score 23):

I am adding this answer based on the discussion I had after posting a [very similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161830/can-we-search-the-inbox-or-comments-tab). It's truly a great feature if we can have it. I proposed the feature based on Stack Overflow `inbox` and `comments tab`.

Each time we want to find some interesting questions/answers that we encountered/interacted, currently there is only one way. Which is very tedious.

1. Go one by one each page of the `comments`
2. Go one by one each page of `inbox`
3. Go one by one for each `vote`...

It can consume lots of time obviously.

So along the **most basic keyword search on `comments/responses/inbox`** I suggest having following bonuses as well:-

- Let user categorize them with their own tags (limited number of tags allowed for user based on reps)
- Add into folders (with limited numbers of folders allowed per user based on reps) like in Google inbox ...