# Can we search the inbox or comments tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, global-inbox, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)

I am trying to find some of the great answers and questions that I have seen in SO. Each time I have to go through each of my favorites/casts votes or comments to find it. That's pretty fancy time consuming thing. Perhaps I am missing some FAQ here..

Please share if there's already a way to search the inbox/comments given a keyword.

Edit:
As per the supprotive comments. This can be a great feature. To feed my greed on the this feature, I would also say we include the following going forward:

- Let user categorize them with their own tags (limited number of tags allowed for user based on reps)
- Add into folders (with limited numbers of folders allowed per user based on reps) like in Google inbox ...

  Given some thught to the `stackdatabase` these greedy features might be too unfriendly...

**But at most basic level: Key word search on comments and inbox would be more than enough.**

Comment: Nope, there is no search facility for responses.

Comment: I'd say we should change this into a feature request to have comments be searcable.  Considering that work went into the new search engine, and we clearly have `is:question` and `is:answer` operators, I think we should be able to index the comments and have an `is:comment` operator.

Comment: @casperOne :) thank you! if it becomes a keyword search facility that would be so great. **To feed my greed, you could even let us save them into folders** :D or at **least put our own tags to them**

Comment: Please go upvote this [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords), change this into a feature-request for comment searching, then vote-to-close as a duplicate to point people to that feature-request.

Comment: You should make your edits into an answer on the other post also.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I have a very little idea of how answers work in `meta`... worry later get downvoted :$

Comment: @bonCodigo, on a feature-request an answer is fine that gives alternates and specifics of implementation.

Comment: The unaddressed request to be able to search inbox/notifications has just been asked anew at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304078/215590

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now [search your favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161743/13295), but there is still no functionality to search comments or notifications.

Why don't you turn this into a feature-request for one or both of those?  Actually, don't, [here is one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords), right now it is improperly closed as a dupe of discussion question but I'll cast the first vote to re-open it.

Comment: +1 for finding a supportive post @LanceRoberts :)

Comment: @bonCodigo, I really like the idea and if I remember will throw a bounty on it tomorrow.

Comment: sorry I forgot to accept the answer. So we can wrap the discussion here. ;)