# Is it allowed to send a notification to community about a requested feature question?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

Is there a way to get help from moderator to notify/send notification to community about a  [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? Currently, the only way I see is the bounty system.

I am referring to a feature request that has support and is considered, by the community, feasible to be built. In order to get community attention, can we please seek moderator assistance?

Currently, I have to comment-reply to each user, looking for the ones who I have possibly interacted in the community via questions, answers etc. Hope it's not too much to ask that a moderator may evaluate or qualify if a notification can be sent e.g. like for Winter Bash.

Comment: You're dancing around it, but what is the feature request you'd like to highlight?  Bounties are the preferred way of highlighting it, assuming the question has already been asked.

Comment: RobertHarvey we already have a bounty thanks to @LanceRoberts. This is [the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)?

Comment: Please [do not randomly highlight key-words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back); there's no need and it makes your question more difficult to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators are entirely separate from developers.  Moderators have no say in what is developed, or for that matter (as far as I know) in which threads the developers pay attention to.

There are a number of developers and other SE employees who are quite active on meta and read all/most of the feature requests.  It might not be read in minutes, but given enough time a very high percentage of non-closed feature requests will be seen by someone in a position to have that feature implemented.

There's a good chance any given request has been noticed by a dev after not too long (just given the percentage of questions that are specifically tagged as completed, denied, planned, etc.).  I would imagine questions with lots of positive votes to be noticed a bit quicker, and if you have a good question that doesn't get noticed you can use a bounty to do that.

You do not need to do anything else though, beyond posting a good question and optionally adding a bounty.  Using @ replies towards anyone you think is important just to bug them is more likely to be annoying than helpful, especially since they'd need to have interacted with the question already for the @ reply to actually notify them.