# Search comments by commentator's user-id

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, search

Often I find comments showing the commentator is quite knowledgeable and able to express concepts in a poignant way, and I would like to discover more comments by such a user (in a similar way one could do i.e. on Reddit, YCombinator, etc.).

Is it possible to search comments by commentator's userid on Stack Exchange?

If not, may I suggest it as a feature request?

Comment: I vaguely recall using a SEDE query someone else wrote to look through my own comments, but it's not in my browser history anymore.  I probably found it here or on Meta Stack Overflow, so keep searching.

Comment: See also [Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066) and [other posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/148066).

Comment: Nice, I did not know one could query StackExchange directly. Thank you.