# Search question titles from all questions I have interacted with

Tags: discussion, search, data-explorer

This is basically a follow up to this popular thread, [Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066/393952), with a similar reasoning behind it: I am sure I have seen an question already to a given problem and I vaguely remember the title, but somehow it won't pop up on google or in searching Stackoverflow.

I would want to narrow it down **to questions that I have interacted with,** usually an upvote.

**small update** [user rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) has kindly pointed out that votes are private. So with interaction I would mean, I could have answered or commented on it, or bookmarked it.

Unfortunately I am a complete SQL beginner and I also don't know what the fields are called that should potentially be queried... This thread seems important, but I don't know how to implement the post-type into the query ([Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)).

The query from the mentioned thread is as follows: (it looks in all the user's comments).

```
SELECT Id AS [Comment Link], Score, Text 
  FROM Comments 
 WHERE UPPER(Text) LIKE UPPER('%##CommentText##%')
   AND UserId = '##UserId##'
 ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Comment: your votes (nor those of anyone else) are not stored in SEDE with your userid as voting is anonymous.

Comment: @rene fair enough, good point.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more general about any interaction of mine, i.e. comments, bookmarks, answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't know from SEDE what you have upvoted as Voting is anonymous. For that reason the UserId field in the Votes table is null for most VoteTypeIds.

The following [Union query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1254769?UserId=7941188) might be the closest to achieve what you want. It checks the few tables that does carry a userid and the postid the record is for. I've used PostHistory, Comments, suggestededits and Votes (for favorites(bookmarks)/bounties).

```
select postid [Post Link]
     , creationdate
     , 'H' [type]
from posthistory 
where userid = ##userid##
union
select postid
     , creationdate
     , 'C'
from comments
where userid = ##userid##
union
select postid
     , creationdate
     , 'E'
from suggestededits
where owneruserid = ##userid##
union
select postid
     , creationdate
     , 'V'
from votes -- but not the up and down votes, voting is anonymous
where userid = ##userid##
order by creationdate desc
```

Feel free to fork it and add the text search criteria for each table where applicable

When run today this is what your result looks like:

[image: sede query results showing postlink, creationdate and Type (H, C, V)]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).