# How to get number of upvoted comments?

Tags: support, comment-voting

I know I have seen a link recently to a query to get number of up-voted comments. Can someone post it?

I have seen many questions asking this same questions, but the answers are broken, because they all point to http://statoverflow.com/, and I can not even access that site. Anyone know why?
For example this:
[Is there a way to know when one of my comments gets "upvoted"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19938/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-one-of-my-comments-gets-upvoted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data dumps are featured on http://data.stackexchange.com now.  I think that was site you have there is its former home.

There's [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/540/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress) which will show you how many comments over a score of 5 you have (and thus count towards the Pundit badge.

[Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution) one from the legendary Waffles which will give you the distribution of all of the comments.

There are a few others that are variants on these two, just search in the box.

Answer (score 5):

You can get this live out of our API, with the query:

`http://api.{site}/1.1/users/{userid}/comments?sort=votes&min=1&pagesize=0`

[For your Stack Overflow count](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/476681/comments?sort=votes&min=1&pagesize=0), at time of writing that returns

```
{
  "total": 96,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 0,
  "comments": []
}
```

So, you have 96 upvoted comments

Comment: When I try it this way, it seems to only go so far back.  Is there another setting?  I guess I'll have to use the API and SEDE and meet in the middle! :)

Comment: @jonsca - set `fromdate` and `todate` (unix epoch format) to constrain by time.  By default it doesn't filter at all, but we do exclude deleted comments and comments on deleted posts.

Comment: One of my good comments was just deleted, that was it.  Thanks!