# Is there any way to see statistics on comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-voting

As comments have badges and votes associated with them, I was wondering if there currently is a way to see statistics on comments such as how many comments you have left, how many times your comments have been voted up, etc.

If not, are there any plans for this or a similar feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see a total of how many comments you've posted but you can filter your activity stream on comments only and either count or do some quick math to get a rough number of how many comments you've left:  [my quick math shows you've left 0 comments here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165687/pat8719?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_comments).

Comment upvotes, on the other hand, are not as easy to find, unfortunately.  So the Pundit badge is probably one of those badges that [Jeff and Co would like to be a "surprise"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440)

**edit**: in fact, in retrospect, this question might be a duplicate of that last linked question - [Electorate, Pundit, etc badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440).

Answer (score 5):

To get all of your most current scores, use the API (HT to Kev for [pointing me to this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98361/how-to-get-number-of-upvoted-comments/98373#98373)).  Use

```
 http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/<yer_user_id>/comments?sort=votes&min=5
```

Tack on a `&pagesize=0` if you just want the raw number, and find your user id in the upper right hand corner of your profile.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this (I hope I didn't misunderstood your question) :
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution

Comment: That information can be up to a month behind, though.  The API grabs it fresh.

Comment: @jonsca What am I supposed to do with JSON file?

Comment: Chrome displays it directly, you'll probably have to open it as text.

Comment: @VJo if you're a firefox user, the [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) extension allows you to choose to display it in the browser like chrome does